# Get Last value of timestamp in Azure Data Factory with Cosmos as source

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

My pipeline has 2 activities for this test.  A lookup activity and a stored procedure which simply takes the output of lookup and then uses it as a parameter to execute.

I want to the get the max value of _ts field (Comos DB Unix Timestamp) in a query that I'm writing.

[image]

This is my query on the source:

```
select max(c._ts) AS UnixTimestamp  from c 
where udf.convertTime(c._ts) >= '@{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' 
AND udf.convertTime(c._ts) < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'
```

When I debug this is the translated input:

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
        "query": "select max(c._ts) AS UnixTimestamp  from c \nwhere udf.convertTime(c._ts) >= '2018-11-06T18:19:56Z' \nAND udf.convertTime(c._ts) < '2018-11-06T19:19:56Z'",
        "nestingSeparator": "."
    },
    "dataset": {
        "referenceName": "SourceComosDB",
        "type": "DatasetReference",
        "parameters": {}
    },
    "firstRowOnly": false
}
```

The output of the lookup activity is coming out to be:

```
{
    "count": 18,
    "value": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US 2)"
}
```

and hence the stored procedure is not executed.

How can I get the max value of _ts within the query?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and did not reproduce your issue.

my sample code:

[image]

lookup activity output with your SQL:

[image]

lookup activity output with your SQL:

[image]

One thing, it can't output `18` values if you used `MAX` query, supposed to be just one value.

The another thing, you should execute the SQK in cosmos db query editor to see if any results match the filter.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was wondering since I'm using MAX, but again the output is showing with count: 18 and and array of empty values

Comment: @MAK So,have you tested the same sql in the cosmos db query editor? Get the same strange results?

Comment: I get an empty array if I run this in the cosmos db query editor.

Comment: @MAK Have you checked if any data matches the query filter? Could you post some details about your test? Such as the data in your database and the query results you saw.